# DateTime::diff - how to get week number?

Tags: php, date, date-difference

I'm having trouble getting "weeks" in **DateTime::diff** function

Here's my code:

```
$date1 = new DateTime("2017-05-14");
$date2 = new DateTime("2017-06-14");
$interval = $date1->diff($date2);
echo $interval->m.' '.($interval->m > 1 ? 'months' : 'month');
```

It worked if I'm going to get the "month" count, but I want to get the weeks before turning it into a month:

We have 4 weeks in a month (4.34524 to be exact from *Google Unit Converter*), if the difference between start date and the date today exceeds 4 weeks, it should output "1 month" and so on..

Comment: You can get days (`d`) from the DateInterval that `diff()` returns, maybe just multiply by seven to get weeks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d0e0fd10f63fce5b1a33e0ac5e9bf9e3acc87704)):

```
$date1 = new DateTime("2017-06-1");
$date2 = new DateTime("2017-06-15");
$interval = $date1->diff($date2);
//var_export($interval);
if($interval->m>0){  // check if >= 1 month
    echo "{$interval->m} month",($interval->m>1?'s':'');
}else{
    $weeks=floor($interval->days/7);  // if not yet 1 month, calc weeks
    echo "$weeks week",$weeks!=1?'s':'';
}
// output: 2 weeks
```

Answer (score 1):

Calculate days and then divide by 7 for week.
Try this code :

```
$date1 = new DateTime("2017-05-14");
$date2 = new DateTime("2017-06-14");
$interval = $date1->diff($date2);


  $week = floor($date1->diff($date2)->days/7);
  echo $week;
  if($week > 4)
  {
      echo $interval->m.' '.($interval->m > 1 ? 'months' : 'month');
  }
```

Comment: Working! Thanks for the code. I just modified something.

Answer (score -1):

you could do this to get weeks and then make the condition:

```
$daysInAweek = 7;
$weeks = ($interval->days)/$daysInAweek;
if($weeks >= 4) {
  echo 'is a month';
}
```

because a week have 7 days.